# User double entry comma/dot issue

Tags: c#, double, point, readline

I want to save a double user entry in an array, but I get issues with the comma/point.
When I type "3,4" the console displays "3,4" -> Correct/
When I type "3.5" the console displays "34" -> why ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] array = new double[3];
    bool schleife = true;

    while (schleife)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Figure");
            array[0] = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            schleife = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error try again");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Value is: {0}", array[0]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Friends of mine obviously dont have these issues....

Comment: It's your culture setting. In german culture (guessing from "schleife"), double are seperated by `,` instead of `.`. The `.` signifies thousand, as in: `1.000.000,00`.

Comment: It displays `35` on me. What is your culture? `Double.Parse` uses current culture.

Comment: Do not ever, ever, Ever, EVER catch exceptions and throw away the results. It's like peeling a banana, throwing away the banana and eating the peel.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.double.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and how do i change this problem? do i have to change my "visual studio " settings or how is it done?

Comment: @user3087913 just check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the culture in which the application is running?

Also, could you place a breakpoint and check what input is actually stored in your array?

Why I asked you to verify it? The issue is most likely a culture issue, something that really mess up decimals and dates, due to different formats in different cultures.

Probably in you culture, which I assume is "de-DE", where for example the number "Thousand and one hundredth" is written as 1.000,01, while in for example the culture "en-US", that same number is written as 1,000.01.

When working with non-preformatted decimal user input it is always advised to define the default culture in your app. If you don't do this it'll automatically take the culture of the computer it is running on.

Doing this is quite easy, just add this line in your app:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

This will make sure that your application is always running in the desired culture and that all decimal numbers are read correctly.

Off course you can set it to any culture you want

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are from germany? Because you are using the "," as a decimal point.
C# uses your local computer settings to parse a number. Therefor "3.5" will be parsed differently then "3,5".

This is a common problem. You can use `double.Parse("3.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to parse decimals with a ".". However this will not work with a ",".

You have to decide which format you want to use and then keep on using only that format for your application.

You could also set the separator manually using:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
double.Parse("3,5", ci )
```

Comment: this sounds quite confusing for me right now^^ why do only I have this problem and my friends not?

Comment: Maybe because they all enter the numbers using "," (3,5) and not using "." (3.5) like you did.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net [each culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This number format has a `NumberDecimalSeparator` and a `NumberGroupSeparator`. In your case the group separator is a `.` and the decimal separator is a `,`. So the first example is parsed correctly as a decimal in your culture whereas the second one is parsed as a grouped digit.

Comment: and what can i do to make him convert both types in the correct figure?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for :

```
Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine().replace(",","."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;
```

It should work even in Turkey :D